# Can SOTI's MobiControl software interfere with an ASP.Net web service?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, soti

We have a set of WinMo (5.0) devices running a .NET CF application that talks to an ASP.Net web service running on a server.  The devices connect to the network either via ActiveSync through a networked PC or directly to the network via an Ethernet dongle.

**In our development environment, the communication between devices and web service is 100% reliable.  In our production environment, the communications are failing erratically and unpredictably.**  Sometimes calls to the web service (even to a simple test call that just returns a boolean) begin failing every time on a particular device, with the error message "Could not establish connection to network."  This is usually fixed by flip-flopping the selected combo box values on the SETTINGS | NETWORKS screen.  Sometimes calls on a particular device begin failing with a generic "WebException" message.  The fix for this problem (so far) is either to reset the device (i.e. reinstall the OS) or else it just can't be fixed on some devices.

To the best of our knowledge, everything about the DEV and PROD systems are the same (same server and device specs).  The most obvious difference to us is that the PROD devices are all controlled by SOTI's MobiControl (which is server-side software that communicates with a SOTI client application installed on each device), whereas our DEV environment does not have SOTI installed anywhere (obviously we *should* have it there as well - long story).

**Does anybody have any experience with SOTI MobiControl and/or know of any documented problems where SOTI interferes with other communication mechanisms on a device?**

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this issue? I have a problem where SOTI instantly kills my win mo app. May not be related, but I am interested in your solution.

Comment: @dwaz: I no longer work for the same company, so I don't know whether or not this problem was ever resolved. SOTI does all kinds of weird things that you wouldn't expect it to be doing, though, causing hard-to-debug problems. For example, SOTI can automatically encrypt files on the PDA, but it does this at the OS level, so common mobile database engines (like SqlCE and Oracle Lite) that manipulate their own database files below the OS level no longer function. So I'm not at all surprised that SOTI kills apps just to watch them die (to paraphrase Johnny Cash).